# Print struct field tags while unmarshalling JSON content for a field?

Tags: go, unmarshalling

In Go, Is it possible to get the tags from a struct field while I'm unmarshaling JSON content to it? Here's my failed attempt at doing so:

```
package main
import (
  "log"
  "encoding/json"
)
type Person struct {
  ProfileName AltField `json:"profile_name"`
}

type AltField struct {
  Val string
}

func (af *AltField) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
  log.Println("Show tags")
  //log.Println(af.Tag) // I want to see `json:"profile_name"`
  if e := json.Unmarshal(b,&af.Val); e != nil {
    return e
  }
  return nil
}
func main() {
  p := Person{}
  _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"profile_name":"Af"}`),&p)

}
```

I commented out the line `log.Println(af.Tag)` because it causes compilation errors.  If I can get a handle on the tags from the Person struct, that will allow me to develop some other conditional logic.

Is this possible?

Comment: Take a look at the reflect package. It is possible to read out fields and tags of a struct.

Comment: You cannot, at least not from the field only since its type, e.g. `AltField`, may have a different tag while being a field of another struct type. You can get tags of fields of a given struct, but not tags of a field when given the type of the field.

Comment: @mkopriva ok right, so this is a scope issue....I thought I'd ask in case there are options

Answer (score 1):

Use reflection to get the value of struct field tag. The `reflect` package provides functions to work with tags including to get the value of tag

```
package main

import (
  "log"
  "encoding/json"
  "reflect"
)
type Person struct {
  ProfileName AltField `json:"profile_name"`
}

type AltField struct {
  Val string `json:"val"`
}

func (af *AltField) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
  field, ok := reflect.TypeOf(*af).FieldByName("Val")
  if !ok {
    panic("Field not found")
  }
  log.Println(string(field.Tag))

  if e := json.Unmarshal(b,&af.Val); e != nil {
    return e
  }
  return nil
}

func main() {
  p := Person{}
  _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"profile_name":"Af"}`),&p)

}
```

You can only get the value of those field tags which has them. The struct field reflect object should be created for fetching the tags of its fields.

Working Code on [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bwiyqWZfA1y)

Comment: Because my problem is potentially a scope issue. I want to grab the tags within the `func (af *AltField) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error` function.  Not in the scope of the `main` function.

Comment: Your code prints `json:"val"`.  What I'm trying to achieve is for the code to print `json:"profile_name"` from within the unmarshaling function.  Ie. I need to grab the tag of the "parent" struct that the af field was originally attached to. @mkopriva says this is not possible because of scope restrictions.

Comment: @John yes he is absolutely right it is not possible. I have mentioned in the answer also that you need to create a reflect object of the struct whose tag you want to get.